# Collection build method in Rails is destructive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is colleciton.build method destructive?

for example(I referred https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-build)

```rb
class Pet
 belongs_to :person
end

class Person
  has_many :pets
end

new_pet = person.pets.build
# => #<Pet id: nil, name: nil, person_id: 1>

new_pet
# => #<Pet id: nil, name: nil, person_id: 1>
```

I can understand this.
But,

```rb
person.pets
# => [#<Pet id: nil, name: nil, person_id: 1>]
```

person.pets looks destructive because of collection build method.
I think `person.pets` returns empty collection.

I cannot understand this behavior. Why is this?
Docs write about build method as below

> Returns a new object of the collection type that has been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object, but have not yet been saved. You can pass an array of attributes hashes, this will return an array with the new objects.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *destructive*? I assume you think that it is overriding the current `person.pets`. Have you tested this by checking the value of `person.pets` before calling `person.pets.build`, then checking the value of `person.pets` afterwards? `build` should not destroy any data, it should return a new instance and appends the newly created instance to the associated collection.

Comment: @3limin4t0r: perhaps they meant it as "mutating"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's something I thought of as well, that's why I asked for clarification.

Comment: @3limin4t0r
Thanks for comments.
"destructive" means mutating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is "destructive" in a sense that it mutates the collection by adding a new element.

> I cannot understand this behavior. Why is this?

I'm sure that are many reasons, but an obvious one that comes to mind is it simplifies client code. Suppose you have a person who has some pets already and you want to give the user the ability to add new pets.

```
# controller
@person = Person.find(params[:id])
@person.pets.size # => 2
@person.pets.build

# view
<% @person.pets.each do |pet| %>
  <% if pet.persisted? %>
    display pet
  <% else %>
    render new pet form
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You could do something like `@new_pet = Pet.new(person_id: @person.id)` and use this to render the form, but it looks more complex. Plus, the approach above lets you add new elements N at a time: just build N new pets before rendering the page.

Comment: Thank for answer. I  become able to understand this behavior.
And, I know for the first time that "destructive" in ja means "mutating" in en. I've learned a lot from you

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why calling `#new` (`#build` is just an alias for `#new`) mutates the receiver is simplicity.

For example it allows auto-saving:

```
person = Person.new
person.pets.build(name: 'Spot')
person.pets.build(name: 'Professor Fluffy')
person.save!
```

This will insert both the person and then two rows in the pets table. It lets you also create form fields for nested records:

```
def new
  @person = Person.new
  5.times { @person.pets.new }
end
```

This lets us simply call `@person.pets` to get the records we have "seeded":

```
<%= form_with(model: @person) do |f| %>
  <%= fields_for :pets do |pet_fields| %>
    # ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If `#new` didn't mutate the receiver we would have to gather up all the records we have seeded and somehow pass them to the form. That would get really clunky if you have multiple forms on a single page.

Comment: Thanks for answer. exactly, if it does not mutate, we have to gather up them.
 I've learned a lot from you